# create_dataset error- Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large np array that I am using to create a dataset. 0th and 1st index of this array look like this-

```
arr[0]= [122, 954, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arr[1]= [122, 17, 377, 1808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
....
```

Then I am creating a dataset using this array-

```
f.create_dataset("init", data=arr),
```

However it runs into this error

> Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

What could be the reasons behind this error? I am very new to python programming. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `f.create_dataset("init", data=arr.astype(float))`

Comment: What is the `arr` shape and dtype?  The array needs to be multidimensional and numeric.

Comment: I'm guessing `arr` is 1d array of objects, and you are showing us 2 of them, lists of length 100.  If so, are the other elements lists of the same length, or different?

Comment: @COLDSPEED- I tried that and it gave me an error- ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @hpaulj - printing the shape of the array gives me a value(951234,). How can I find out the length of the other elements?

Comment: Try `np.vstack(arr)`.  If the component lists are all the same length this should create a 2d numeric array.

Comment: @hpaulj On doing np.vstack(arr) I get an error - ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.  Does this mean all the component lists are not of the same length?

Comment: Yes, most likely.  Look at `[len(i) for i in arr]`, or its `max` and `min` if large.